# ANT check if it is equal to a value then execute the tasks

Tags: xml, shell, xslt, ant, ant-contrib

I am trying to hard to achieve the below requirement

I am writing a logic inside ant build file to compare the value of my system ip address and based on that do an scp task , I am getting the local IP address inside a shell script and passing it as part the ANT arguments

Shell Script contents

export IP_ADDR=`ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`

$ant_home/ant -listener $listener -Dlocal.ipaddress=${IP_ADDR}  -buildfile BuildHome/build.xml

Now , user invokes this shell script and along with a property file.

Property file values

```
<user-request>

        <prop-value name = "TESTApp">
                <action>install</action>
                <target-location>/apps/properties/messagadapter</target-location>
                <members-info>
                   <ip-address>10.xx.xx.xx</ip-address>
                    <ip-address>10.yy.yy.yy</ip-address>
                </members-info>
                <file-name>test12.xml</file-name>
                <file-name>test23.xml</file-name>
        </prop-value>

</user-request>
```

I have written all the necessary XSLT transformations and was able  to transform the user xml as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project name="test" default="request" basedir=".">
<target name="process-request">
<ant antfile="build.xml" target="property" dir=".">
<property name="package.name" value="TESTApp"/>
<property name="target" value="install"/>
<property name="target.location" value="/tmp/properties/applications1"/>
<property name="file.list" value="test12.xml,test23.xml"/>
<property name="member.ipaddress" value="10.xx.xx.xx,10.yy.yy.yy"/>
</ant>
</target>
</project>
```

My build.xml as below , i want to check if the ipaddress is equal to the localipaddress and then do the necessary operation but for some reason it never goes into the IF loop , though the value is equal to the local ip address it always skips the if condition and goes to the else ,

```
<target name = "deploy" depends="defineAntContribTasks">
     <echo message = "Copying Property files ${file.list} to ${target.location} "/>
     <echo message = " The value of the local ipaddress us .... ${local.ipaddress} "/>
      <echo message = " The value of the member ino ... ${member.ipaddress} "/>
     <for list="${member.ipaddress}" param="ipaddress">
       <sequential>
         <if>
             <equals arg1="@{ipaddress}" arg2="{local.ipaddress}"/>
             <then>
                   <copy todir="${target.location}" overwrite="true">
                       <fileset dir="${input.prop}" includes = "${file.list}"/>
                    </copy>
             </then>
             <else>
                   <echo message = " Inside the else loop ... "/>
                   <echo message = " The value of the ip is ... @{ipaddress}"/>
                   <property name="remoteipaddress" value="@{ipaddress}" />
                   <scp keyfile="/home/fsadmin/.ssh/id_dsa" todir="fsadmin@${remoteipaddress}:${target.location}" passphrase="" trust="true">
                      <fileset dir="${input.prop}" includes="${file.list}"/>
                   </scp>
              </else>
         </if>
       </sequential>
     </for>
  </target>
```

i am not sure if this is failing because we are doing a string to int operation or some other reason , I am not sure where I am missing the condition can some one please guide me

Comment: Looks like you are missing **$** in _equals_ check : `<equals arg1="@{ipaddress}" arg2="${local.ipaddress}"/>`

Comment: yes sir, i should apologize for the silly mistake ... Thank you very much ...